# Facebook login always comes back as cancelled. (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently trying implement Facebook login using the 4.0 version of the SDK, this also happens with the 3.+ version. When I call **logInWithReadPermissions** (4.0 version) or **openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions** (3.+ version). The closure/block is called immediately with **isCancelled** (4.0 version) and **ClosedFailedLogin** (3.+ version) before the user can make a selection (*cancel* or *ok*). I thought it may be a problem with the URL Scheme in my plist settings but I've checked it over and over and everything seems to be right. Just wondering if anyone may have any ideas on solving this problem. My Bundle ID is right, single signin is on, native app is enabled, in the Facebook dev console. See some sample code and configurations below (4.0 version).

**Login Call:**
[image: Login Call]

**AppDelegate:**
[image: AppDelegate]

**Plist:**
[image: Plist]

Comment: In the future, please avoid posting *screenshots* to show your code. It uses up more SO server space, isn't as readable on different sized screens, doesn't scroll off to the side, and isn't searchable as text by search engines.  Just paste in code as text and use the editor's code formatting button.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a **duplicate** of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358661/fbsdkloginmanager-loginwithpublishpermissions-always-returns-iscancelled-yes (which was actually posted after this post). You can find the answer there, regarding the missing call to [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the some problem but I found a workaround. You can set the login behaviour of the Login Manager to use the Facebook details on the phone. The default behaviour is FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemNative and that tries to use the Facebook app first and then if its not there, it uses a web modal.

Instead of doing it that way and passing around urls that don't seem to work you can set the login behaviour as ***FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount***.

Long story short, try:

```
let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager();
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
// call login method of choice here
```

Comment: answer is expired

Answer (score 14):

With Facebook SDK version 4 I only had to add this to my application delegate on iOS 10 & Swift 3 to make the authentication work. Before that I also only had cancelled logins.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the fix I was missing for receiving the callbacks after the user signs in with the app.

Comment: This is correct. Not mentioned in FB Swift Documentation. Its mentioned in ObjC documentation though.

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue login method always return **canacelled** then I add below things in **info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

and in **AppDelegate** update **didFinishLaunching** method and add new method like below

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
{
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Login method is given below:

```
@objc func loginButtonClicked() {
    let  loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.loginBehavior = .systemAccount
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile,.userFriends,.email ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
            //Do further code...
        }
    }
}
```

it works for me in **Swift 3.0** and **SDK 4.17.0**, I hope it works for you Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Did you add function to AppDelegate?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had very similar problem while adding LoginButton in my app by following this tutorial → https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login.

After clicking the Facebook Connect button and finishing the authorization, it always returns with status 'cancelled'.
I tried many solutions and finally the following worked:

In **AppDelegate.swift**, add the following 2 functions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue too. It turned out that the app bundle id (in project configuration) mismatched with the app bundle id configured in the facebook app dashboard. After fixing the bundle id, the login worked just fine.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the wrong AppDelegate method was being called.  It was calling

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {...
```

instead of

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {...
```

So i had to add this to the first AppDelegate method (the one that was being called):

```
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: "com.apple.mobilesafari", annotation: nil)
```

Note that i had to pass the safari bundle ID explicitly, otherwise the FB account delegate would get `isCancelled = true`

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem from past 1 month. I was integrating facebook login with firebase in ios 10 swift 3. Finally, I m able to successfully implement it. I corrected it by making following changes in AppDelegate file.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
          return true
    }


    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,  open: url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
            return shouldOpen
    }

    // for iOS below 9.0
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,open: url as URL!,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
        return shouldOpen
    }
```

I Hope it might help others

tested on ios 10.2 Emulator, iPhone 6 Plus running with 10.2

Comment: Have you done this with Facebook and Google login? I'm facing the same issue, and this solution doesn't seem to help in my case

Answer (score 1):

My issue was caused from me modally presenting a loading view controller, which I had being dismissed when the view disappeared. Since FBSDK calls the viewWillDisappear method when transitioning to Safari or the app, it was closing the view and the FB login screen. Same thing can happen if you present the login over a UIAlertController.

Comment: This solved my problem. I had an active UIAlertController and the modal FB Login was being dismissed automatically. I just needed to present the modal FB Login after the UIAlertController dismiss closure.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2020-10-09:

FBSDK version 4.38.0 uses UIWebView, which is currently being discontinued by Apple and will be completely discontinued in December.

ORIGINAL:

I've been having the same problem and none of the other answers here worked for me. I went through the Facebook documentation carefully to make sure that I had everything correct, which I did. After some research, I discovered that this is a problem within the FBSDK itself starting with version 4.39.0. As it turned out, I had been using FBSDK version 4.40.0. The problem was completely resolved when I reverted to FBSDK version 4.38.0.

[Here's a link which explains how to revert to FBSDK version 4.38.0 if you are using cocoapods](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/298#issuecomment-449626683)

If however you are like me and prefer not to use cocoapods, [here is a link to download FBSDK version 4.38.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

13 january 2019

Solved for me :

**Delete Podfile.lock 

Delete Pods folder** 

**replace the facebook pods** in your Podfile **with this version** of facebook 
 
**pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0' 

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'** 
 

now please notice that if you have FacebookShareKit or anything else for facebook you have to change it to the same version you are using which is 4.38.0

run your terminal with pod install 
**open your project, go to Product > Clean Build Folder** 
run the app and try.

worked for me, if it does for you let everybody knows.

**original post:** https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/298#issuecomment-449626683

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Don't mix **FBSDKApplicationDelegate** and **SDKApplicationDelegate**

Solved it with the next Swift 4 code in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let appId = SDKSettings.appId
    if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)") && url.host == "authorize" { // facebook
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case that using React-Native, FacebookSDK and Deeplink together, I need to have only one openUrl inside AppDelegate.m. More details explanation is in https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md#32-ios-project