# FBSDKLoginManager logInWithPublishPermissions always returns isCancelled=YES

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am having trouble figuring out how to log a user into my app. `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is nil, so I am calling:

```
[[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init] logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:…];
```

as per the included sample project. This switches to the Facebook app, but the message says "You have already authorized *App Name*.". I click OK and it goes back into the app, but `grantedPermissions` and `declinedPermissions` are both `nil` on the result, and `isCancelled` is `YES`. `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is still `nil`.

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to get `currentAccessToken` to be filled in. It seems to me the call to `logInWithPublishPermissions` should do that, but it isn't.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should try adding in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

This would get u `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` when user is logged in.

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

If this method is not present into AppDelegate then it results into cancelled state.

Refer to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#startcoding

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed those calls somehow.

Comment: @Dheeraj Singh : You saved my day brother. :)

Comment: i had done both the thing and still i am getting result.cancelled = true

Answer (score 29):

This can happen when your Facebook App doesn't have "publish_actions" permission, or **you're not using a test user**.

On Facebook, go to manage your app, then make sure that the Facebook user you're using is defined under "Roles" as an admin or tester.

If it's not a test user or admin - Facebook will require "publish_actions" permission to be reviewed and approved before allowing your app to use it, until then you'll receive a "isCancelled=YES" result.

After testing your app with this permission, it is possible to submit this permission for review, you'll need to upload a binary that demonstrates usage of this permission with exact details on how to use it. After it's approved, you'll be able to use it with non-test Facebook users.

Comment: Wow, this was the solution.  So much time to understand why I always get iscancelled = YES...

MANY thanks Kof.

Comment: This was also the solution for me. I had done all that other stuff but was on a different device that was logged into a different account that wasn't a test user.

Comment: I added `publish_actions` when calling  `FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithPublishPermissions()` but it is still not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Since FBSDKLoginKit 4.6.0, the `logInWithReadPermissions` and `logInWithPublishPermissions` methods of FBSDKLoginManager seems to have additional `fromViewController` argument and use that to present modals.

I was calling `logInWithPublishPermissions` inside the callback of `logInWithReadPermissions`, which at that point **the modal is not fully dismissed yet**. (I know it's a bad practice to ask permission when it's not needed, but in my case this seems to be the right place to do.) This cause it to fail with `isCancelled` equals to YES. I added some delay and wait for the modal to be fully dismissed fixed the problem.

Comment: If you only need `public_profile` read permission, you can just ask for publish permissions without having read permissions in advance. The SDK will handle it by itself by first asking the user for `public_profile`, then the write permissions you requested. This saves you from handling the dialog flow by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I landed here, turns out I was only using the deprecated application openURL method because i was using google sign in too. To support iOS 8 and before you have to implement both the current and the deprecated method:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]) || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

The deprecated is the second.

Note: The FBSDK method is added after the google one with an or "||" operator but the order doesn't matter and if you wanna only use facebook method just erase the method and the or operator.

Note 2: As swift 3 still stabilizing the method name can change I suggest you always use the auto complete from XCode when overriding and implementing a delegate's method.

Hope this Helps o/

Answer (score 1):

`FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult.isCancelled` is unexpectedly `YES`:

The SDK will report a cancellation if the user explicitly taps a cancel button in the login dialogs, or if they manually app switch back to your app (known as an implicit cancellation). You should make sure you are not initiating a login flow as part of your app `delegate`'s lifecycle (such as starting a login inside `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`) as that will mimic an implicit cancellation. If you must, dispatch the login initiation later to the main queue so that the app delegate's lifecycle completes first.

Answer (score 1):

**This method works in iOS 9**

```
// Facebook Login Completion delegate
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (result){
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        NSLog(@"%@",result.grantedPermissions);
       [self getFacebookData:result];
     }
}  

- (void)getFacebookData:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result{

   if (![result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
   {
      FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
      login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
      [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
       {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                     [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, email, id"}]
                      startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                              [self registerWithFacebook:result];
                          }else{
                              NSLog(@"%@",error);
                          }
                      }];
                 }


             }
         }
     }];


 }else{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, email, id"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                 [self registerWithFacebook:result];
             }else{
                 NSLog(@"%@",error);
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

}

**NOTE** : Use **FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb** instead of **FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser**. This will surely work

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you are not calling for `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken` INSIDE your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. The setup in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` needs to complete so the token can initialize before you try to log in to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and i spent almost 2 hours to resolve the issue. What i did is

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
**[login logOut];** // adding this single line fixed my issue
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:self  handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Process error");
     } else if (result.isCancelled) {
         NSLog(@"Cancelled");
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Logged in");
         [self GetData];
     }
 }] // I called this logout function
```

and the issue was fixed

i was using both google and Facebook login so i had to implement my openURL method like this, iOS 9+

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    if ([[url absoluteString] containsString:@"YOURFBID"]) {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
    } else {
        return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                   sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                          annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

// you can perform further any operations using the access token

```
- (void)GetData {
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        NSDictionary *AccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, picture.type(large) ,last_name"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 //NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                 //NSDictionary *Result = result;
                 NSDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[AccessToken tokenString] forKey:@"access_token"];

             } else {
                 [self showAlertController:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
             }
         }];
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(nonnull NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                          options:options];
}

// **Still need this for iOS8**
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(nonnull id)annotation
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.check already added

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

2.check already added

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(nonnull id)annotation
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

3.
write this statement `[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];` 
before

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

4.call logInWithReadPermissions method in     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}

Answer (score -2):

call this methord,

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_friends"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
   code
}];
```