# How to implement login with FB using FBSDKLoginManager?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-sdk-4.0

While using this method
`([login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)`

always getting result as `isCancelled` to `YES`. And getting `AccessToken` as `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

and add this method in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Credit goes to [FBSDKLoginManager logInWithPublishPermissions always returns isCancelled=YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358661/fbsdkloginmanager-loginwithpublishpermissions-always-returns-iscancelled-yes)

Comment: Hi channi, I have these two methods in appdelegate.m even i am not getting access token

Comment: have you checked this link yet https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#startcoding to verify your app settings

Comment: please do share the issue when resolved it might help someone