# PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions, swift 1.2, user returned is nil

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse 1.7.1, Facebook SDK 4.0.1, Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.3.1

In executing this code, I'm getting a nil PFUser:

```
var permissions = [ "public_profile" ]

PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions,  block: {  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let user = user {
         if user.isNew {
             println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
         } else {
             println("User logged in through Facebook!")
         }
    } else {
        println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
    }
})
```

PFUser returned is nil, thus I see "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." in the logs.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is in the VC, viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: Have you tried adding and logging the `error`variable?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358661/fbsdkloginmanager-loginwithpublishpermissions-always-returns-iscancelled-yes/29365852#29365852

Comment: You say you are using Facebook SDK 4.0, then you should be using `PFFacebookUtilsV4`, which is separate from `PFFacebookUtils`

Comment: The error variable is nil.  I'm currently using the code mentioned in the other stackoverflow post. I'm using PFFacebookUtilsV4.

Comment: The code started working this afternoon.  PFM. ;-)  Closing this out.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the code started working?