# ios Facebook Login button - doesn't change to Log out

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I'm using Xcode 6 & Facebook iOS SDK 4.3,
I embedded the code, according to [Facebook's guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3) and the login works, BUT 
from some reason -

after I login, the button doesn't change to "Log out", and stays "Log in with Facebook".

did anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so I started all over, and followed the [instructions from the guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#login-button):

1.in the **viewController.h** file:

```
#import < FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h> //<-delete the space

#import < FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>//<-delete the space

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;
```

2.in the **viewController.m** file:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
   if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
   // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller. 
   }

   self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];

   FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
}
```

---

and after that didn't work, [I've found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358661/fbsdkloginmanager-loginwithpublishpermissions-always-returns-iscancelled-yes) that mentioned I also need to add few things to the AppDelegate **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** :

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
}
```

and then it worked!
finally I had the **Log in** button changed to **Log out**!

Comment: Thanks for that! I've been struggling with FB's docs. They are very obscure in my opinion. Anyway you solved my problem :)

Comment: Adding- it turns that its not just that the login changes to logout, but the login process won't finish with out `application:openUrl:sourceApplication:annotation`. So now I can use the login result object.

Comment: As said by @Gab, in simulators u may not see logout button change automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue, and couldn't find the answer anywhere.
Turns out it was a Simulator problem; once I ran the same code on the device (iOS 9.3.1) everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to enable keychain sharing capability